# R ggplot: overlaying a kernel density chart on the y axis of a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot chart

```
q3 <- ggplot(y, aes(T,C))+  geom_line()
```

and the kernel density

```
den <-density(y$C)
```

How can I overlay a kernel density chart on the y axis?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "overlaying a kernel density chart on the y axis". Could you provide more explanation, or perhaps an example image to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: You can often get the "sideways" plotting by reversing the x and y roles, so in extra layer calls it would mean reversing the aes() arguments .... if I understand ggplot syntax correctly, which I often don't.

Comment: I'm guessing you want some fraction of the methods used in this earlier SO posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on DWin's idea, this might be the sort of thing you're looking for:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                  y = 1:100,
                  z = rnorm(100))

ggplot(dat) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = y/100,y = x/100)) + 
    geom_density(aes(x = z)) + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Note the reversal of the `x` and `y` aesthetics in `geom_point`.