# 2D filled.contour plot with 1D histograms by axes

Tags: r, graphics, histogram

My task is simple, just to plot the following, but the plot in the middle should be a filled.contour plot:
http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graph/Scatterplot_with_marginal_histograms_78

Background: I prefer filled.contour rather than hist2d. Because, I could use kernel smooth, so the plot for discrete data won't be too ugly. I also tried image() and then contour(), but the number on contour is not clear and no indication about the color.

My problem: in filled.contour function, it uses layout() for filledcontour() plot and rect() plot (color bar). However, I use layout() in outside code to organize 2 histograms and one filled.contour plot. Looks like, the layout outside is shadowed by filled.contour(). I am not sure how R deal with this problem. Should I rewrite filled.contour() somehow?

If we can plot in R like matplotlib in python, something like the following link will make life much easier:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html

Comment: There is already some nice work out there on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546256/two-way-density-plot-combined-with-one-way-density-plot-with-selected-regions-in/11552979#11552979 and stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2/8545618 . I'm pretty sure I can do it in base graphics but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble when existing ggplot solutions are already available. Please respond regarding whether those are adequate.

Comment: Also ... if those are not adequate you should post data and code documenting a reasonable starting point for enhancement. Otherwise people here are likely to downvote the question as showing minimal effort on your part.

Comment: +1 to DWin's comment.  You're going to need a picture of your current graph, plus some sample data and code to work from in order to get much interest from the SO community.

Comment: Downvoting for crossposting and voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an identical question to [this one on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51722/2d-filled-contour-plot-with-1d-histograms-by-axes-by-r/51728#51728).  See the answer there (which is to use `.filled.contour` instead of `filled.contour`.

Comment: And it has been migrated, so this one should be closed.