# 3-variables plotting heatmap ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap, density-plot

I'm currently working on a very simple `data.frame`, containing three columns:

`x` contains x-coordinates of a set of points,

`y` contains y-coordinates of the set of points, and

`weight` contains a value associated to each point;

Now, working in `ggplot2` I seem to be able to plot contour levels for these data, but i can't manage to find a way to fill the plot according to the variable `weight`. Here's the code that I used:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill=weight)) + 
  geom_density_2d() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

You can see that there's no filling whatsoever, sadly.
I've been trying for three days now, and I'm starting to get depressed.

Specifying `fill=weight` and/or `color = weight` in the general `ggplot` call, resulted in nothing. I've tried to use different geoms (tile, raster, polygon...), still nothing. Tried to specify the `aes` directly into the geom layer, also didn't work.
Tried to convert the object as a ppp but `ggplot` can't handle them, and also using base-R plotting didn't work. I have honestly no idea of what's wrong!
I'm attaching the first 10 points' data, which is spaced on an irregular grid:

```
x = c(-0.13397460,-0.31698730,-0.13397460,0.13397460,-0.28867513,-0.13397460,-0.31698730,-0.13397460,-0.28867513,-0.26794919)

y = c(-0.5000000,-0.6830127,-0.5000000,-0.2320508,-0.6547005,-0.5000000,-0.6830127,-0.5000000,-0.6547005,0.0000000)

weight = c(4.799250e-01,5.500250e-01,4.799250e-01,-2.130287e+12,5.798250e-01,4.799250e-01,5.500250e-01,4.799250e-01,5.798250e-01,6.618956e-01)
```

any advise? The desired output would be something along these lines:

[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qXDJ.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you are misusing a density plot. Density plots are meant to estimate underlying probability density  functions (a function that integrates to 1 over the sample space). Maybe it sounds like you want some form of interpolation to spread function values out over a surface? But in that case you would need to choose some form of statistical modeling for the interpolation.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `filled.contour` function? You would first need to interpolate your data with something like `library(akima)` `int.ds <- interp(df$x,df$y,df$weight,duplicate="strip")`. Then you could do something along the lines of `filled.contour(int.ds)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description `geom_density` doesn't sound right.

You could try [`geom_raster`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill = weight)) + 
     geom_raster() +
     coord_fixed(ratio = 1)  + 
     scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(7)) # colourmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second-best using `fill=..level..`. [There is a good explanation on `..level..` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206623/what-does-level-mean-in-ggplotstat-density2d).

```
# load libraries
  library(ggplot2)
  library(RColorBrewer)
  library(ggthemes)

# build your data.frame
 df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, weight=weight)

# build color Palette
  myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")), space="Lab")


# Plot
  ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill=..level..) ) + 
      stat_density_2d( bins=11, geom = "polygon") +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(11)) +
      theme_minimal() +
      coord_fixed(ratio = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't use weights.

Comment: Hi @Axeman, you're correct. My answer does not use `fill=weights`, that's why I said it's a 'second best'. As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to pass a data vector to `fill` in `stat_density_2d`. A bit of explanation in the [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206623/what-does-level-mean-in-ggplotstat-density2d/32207207?noredirect=1#comment57518193_32207207) I posted with my answer.