# Density Heatmap with 1 Dimension Density Plot Alignment

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, ggmap, density-plot

I am using the method outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546256/two-way-density-plot-combined-with-one-way-density-plot-with-selected-regions-in?answertab=votes#tab-top) in order to create a density heatmap on a map paired with the one dimensional x and y density plots. I was able to produce the following image: [Density Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXoXv.jpg)

However, I am having difficulty aligning the shaded regions in the top density plot with the heatmap on the map. I discovered that this has to to with the fact that I am applying a mercator projection in the code to produce the heatmap, whereas the top and right density plots are just using the coordinates from the data.

Is there a way that I can align the projected coordinates in the heatmap with the nonprojected coordinates in the one dimensional density plot?

Below is the relevant section of my code (I used the grid/gtable packages to combine the different graphs).

**EDIT: The data is comprised of three columns: UniqueID, Lon, and Lat. In this case all the Lon/Lat pairs are in/around New York City, but for troubleshooting purposes the exact pairs don't matter as long as they can be projected.**

```
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)   
library(ggmap) 

ny <- get_map(location = "Washington Heights, New York City", zoom = 12, color = "bw")

    ggm <- ggmap(ny, extent = "normal", maprange = F) %+% data +
          aes(x = Lon, y = Lat) +
          stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..,
                             alpha = ..level..), color = "darkgreen",
                         geom = "polygon", show.legend = TRUE) +
          geom_polygon(aes(x, y), 
                       data.frame(x = c(Inf, Inf, -73.90, -73.90), y = c(Inf, 40.84, 40.84, Inf)),
                       alpha = 0.5, colour = NA, fill = "red") +
          coord_map(projection = "mercator",
                    xlim = c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lon, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lon),
                    ylim = c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lat, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lat))

    xd <- data.frame(density(data$Lon)[c("x", "y")])
    gg1 <- ggplot(xd, aes(x, y)) +
      theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = NA),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA)) +
      labs(y = "Density") +
      geom_area(data = subset(xd, x > -73.90), fill = "red") +
      geom_line() +
      coord_cartesian(c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lon, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lon))

image <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(ggm), pattern = "panel", trim = TRUE, fixed=TRUE)
image <- gtable_add_cols(image, unit(0.2, "null"), 1)
image <- gtable_add_grob(image, gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(gg1), pattern = "panel", trim = TRUE, fixed=TRUE), 1, 1)
```

Comment: Without access to `data`, it is difficult to provide help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added a description of the data frame to my question, hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is to do with the projection. If you check the x-range for the top density plot and the x-range for the map, I don't think they are the same. Similarly, the y-range for the right density plot compared to the y-range of the map. See to the bottom for code. The reason the ranges are not the same is that, by default, `ggmap` has no expansion factor for the axes whereas `ggplot`, by default, has an expansion factor.   Set `expand = c(0,0)` in the two density plots.

There seems to be another issue. The right density plot needs to be flipped, but the flipping interferes with the limits set via `coord_cartesian`. If I set the limits using `xlim` (and `ylim`), then the limits remain after the flipping.

```
library(ggmap)
library(gtable)
library(ggplot2)    
library(grid)


ny <- get_map(location = "Washington Heights, New York City", zoom = 12, color = "bw")

# Pretend data
set.seed(5126)
df = data.frame(Lon = rnorm(100, mean = -73.90, sd = .015), Lat = rnorm(100, mean = 40.84, sd = .015))

# Map
   ggm <- ggmap(ny, extent = "normal", maprange = F) %+% df +
          aes(x = Lon, y = Lat) +  
          stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..,
                             alpha = ..level..),
                         geom = "polygon", show.legend = TRUE) +
          geom_polygon(aes(x, y), 
                       data.frame(x = c(Inf, Inf, -73.90, -73.90), y = c(Inf, 40.84, 40.84, Inf)),
                       alpha = 0.5, colour = NA, fill = "red") + geom_point() +
          coord_map(projection = "mercator", 
                    xlim = c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lon, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lon),
                    ylim = c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lat, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lat)) 


# Top density plot
xd <- data.frame(density(df$Lon)[c("x", "y")])

gg1 <- ggplot(xd, aes(x, y)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = NA),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA)) +
  labs(y = "Density") +
  geom_area(data = subset(xd, x > -73.90), fill = "red") +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lon, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lon), expand = c(0,0)) 

image <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(ggm), pattern = "panel", trim = TRUE, fixed=TRUE)
image <- gtable_add_rows(image, unit(0.2, "null"), 0)
image <- gtable_add_grob(image, gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(gg1), pattern = "panel", trim = TRUE, fixed=TRUE), 1, 1) 

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(image)


# Right density plot
xd <- data.frame(density(df$Lat)[c("x", "y")])

gg2 <- ggplot(xd, aes(x, y)) +
   theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = NA),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA)) +
   labs(y = "Density") +
   geom_area(data = subset(xd, x > 40.84), fill = "red") + 
   geom_line() + 
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(attr(ny, "bb")$ll.lat, attr(ny, "bb")$ur.lat), expand = c(0,0)) +
   coord_flip() 

image <- gtable_add_cols(image, unit(0.2, "null"), 1)
image <- gtable_add_grob(image, gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(gg2), pattern = "panel", trim = TRUE, fixed=TRUE), 2, 2) 

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(image)
```

**Edit** Updating to ggplot2 ver 3.0.0

```
# Check that the ranges for the density plots are the same as the ranges for the map
top = ggplot_build(gg1)
right = ggplot_build(gg2)
map = ggplot_build(ggm)

top$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range
map$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range

right$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
map$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
```

[image]