# Good contour/density plots for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I want to do a contour plot for this data

```
        model1        model2
1  0.006889929 0.005679936
2  0.007700212 0.005249357
3  0.008565160 0.004499936
4  0.006881213 0.005151137
5  0.008636678 0.006632931
6  0.007141556 0.005622523
7  0.008368942 0.005443024
8  0.006818685 0.005273998
9  0.006696313 0.006221722
10 0.006268623 0.004654712
11 0.007999088 0.005780017
12 0.007532648 0.005547954
13 0.006554138 0.006242407
14 0.008131300 0.004914134
15 0.006231241 0.004716008
16 0.006426665 0.005245560
17 0.008686260 0.007035450
18 0.007636747 0.006508285
19 0.005485265 0.004489133
20 0.005694367 0.005601413
21 0.008493238 0.005385272
22 0.007729237 0.006110326
23 0.010172940 0.005355400
24 0.007146254 0.007183295
25 0.006360539 0.006388278
26 0.008034973 0.005276761
27 0.008438192 0.004589171
28 0.007425142 0.007708877
29 0.006258370 0.004478218
30 0.009314826 0.007461234
31 0.006842500 0.006158923
32 0.009193691 0.005661072
33 0.008708791 0.006167508
34 0.007306337 0.005066528
35 0.007275601 0.004493423
36 0.006115221 0.005373104
37 0.006952139 0.004571620
38 0.007906732 0.006197955
39 0.007330278 0.005857626
40 0.008920438 0.007038646
41 0.008047256 0.005619965
42 0.006813636 0.005175007
43 0.007514715 0.008053758
44 0.007525681 0.005289664
45 0.007197230 0.005243756
46 0.011364365 0.006323551
47 0.007843592 0.005399640
48 0.006785430 0.004375154
49 0.008328563 0.005376976
50 0.007069436 0.005173282
```

and I use the code

```
set.seed (123)
xvar <- sqrt(VarianceLOm1[9,])
yvar <-   sqrt(VarianceLOm2[9,])
myd <- data.frame (xvar, yvar)

p1 <- ggplot(myd,aes(x=xvar,y=yvar))+
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon") +
  coord_cartesian(c(0.003, 0.012), c(0.003, 0.012)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

which produces the density plot

[image]

But to be honest this doesn't look great, as it looks all patchy. I was wondering if there are any better plots to use. It needs to be 2D ideally, I've looked at 3D density plots and they aren't what I need.

I looked at this thread for reference, and ideally I'd like my plots the be like the ones in this thread but I can't seem to get it to work. ([two-way density plot combined with one way density plot with selected regions in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546256/two-way-density-plot-combined-with-one-way-density-plot-with-selected-regions-in?rq=1))

Complete code

```
p1 <- ggplot(myd,aes(x=xvar,y=yvar))+
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon") +
  coord_cartesian(c(0.003, 0.012), c(0.003, 0.012)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p2 <- ggplot(myd, aes(x = xvar)) + stat_density() +
  coord_cartesian(c(0.003, 0.012))
p3 <- ggplot(myd, aes(x = yvar)) + stat_density() + 
  coord_flip(c(0.03, 0.012))

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
gt3 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p3))

gt1 <- gtable_add_cols(gt, unit(0.3, "null"), pos = -1)
gt1 <- gtable_add_rows(gt1, unit(0.3, "null"), pos = 0)

gt1 <- gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt2$grobs[[which(gt2$layout$name == "panel")]],
                                 1, 4, 1, 4)
gt1 <- gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt2$grobs[[which(gt2$layout$name == "axis-l")]],
                                 1, 3, 1, 3, clip = "off")

gt1 <- gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt3$grobs[[which(gt3$layout$name == "panel")]],
                                 4, 6, 4, 6)
gt1 <- gtable_add_grob(gt1, gt3$grobs[[which(gt3$layout$name == "axis-b")]],
                                 5, 6, 5, 6, clip = "off")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt1)
```

and it looks like this

[image]

see the second plot is nowhere to be found, and the axis are a bit messed up

Comment: When you say you "can't seem to get it to work", what exactly did you try? What errors did you get?

Comment: Edited the question for you, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry I need to post pictures as screenshots at the moment because I dont have enough rep