# Discrete data for ggplot stat_density2d

Tags: r, 2d, ggplot2

stat_density2d seems don't like discrete data. My code following cannot be plotted, and have such errors on R 2.15.2:

> Error in contourLines(x = sort(unique(data$x)), y =
>   sort(unique(data$y)),  :    no proper 'z' matrix specified In
>   addition: Warning messages: 1: Removed 10000 rows containing
>   non-finite values (stat_contour).  2: In min(x) : no non-missing
>   arguments to min; returning Inf 3: In max(x) : no non-missing
>   arguments to max; returning -Inf

On R 2.15.3, the error is:

> Error in function (x, y, h, n = 25, lims = c(range(x), range(y)))  :
>   bandwidths must be strictly positive

Probably because of the limitation n = 25.

```
a<-url("http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ajing/Files/TestData.RData")
load(a)

library(ggplot2)
p1<-ggplot(myd, aes(x=xvar,y=yvar)) + stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon")
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
```

Anyway to avoid this error? Or other recommended 2D histogram plots?

As I need two marginal histograms, ggplot is better than filled.contour for me.

Comment: I get a different error message, `bandwidths must be strictly positive` (from kde2d). There are no discrete data here.

Comment: OK, because you have a newer R version. My version is 2.15.2. 2.15.3 will give your error

Comment: It will be a `ggplot2` version issue more likely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scatterplot with marginal histograms in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Yes, I like contour plot with marginal histograms in this situation, but I have the above problem. Do you know how to catch warning message?

Comment: Update R and ggplot2!

Comment: How to upgrade ggplot2 for R in ubuntu?

Comment: What exactly do you expect a density plot to do with categorical inputs? Maybe you want `geom_tile` or `geom_bin2d`?

Comment: Even I upgrade both R and ggplot2, it still has "bandwidths must be strictly positive" error.

Comment: Not exactly categorical, but I would say it count data. geom_bin2d can work, but I want to see gradient details for 2d plot. geom_bin2d is too obscure.