# scatterplot with alpha transparent histograms in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How can scatter plots with alpha transparent, scale-less histograms can be made in R, like this figure?

looks like it's not made in ggplot2.[image]

does anyone know what command is used?

Comment: This thread gets you close, but maybe not quite to where you want to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2

Comment: See also http://blog.mckuhn.de/2009/09/learning-ggplot2-2d-plot-with.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,mean=c(1,5)),y=rlnorm(100,meanlog=c(8,6)),group=1:2)

p1 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=factor(group))) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none",plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"points"))

theme0 <- function(...) theme( legend.position = "none",
                               panel.background = element_blank(),
                               panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                               panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                               panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
                               axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                               axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                               axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                               axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                               axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                               axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"null"),
                               axis.ticks.margin = unit(0,"null"),
                               panel.border=element_rect(color=NA),...)

p2 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=x,colour=factor(group),fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme0(plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,0,2.2),"lines")) 
  
p3 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=y,colour=factor(group),fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.5) + 
  coord_flip()  + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = NULL,breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL,breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme0(plot.margin = unit(c(0,1,1.2,0),"lines"))

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p2,ncol=2,widths=c(3,1)),
             arrangeGrob(p1,p3,ncol=2,widths=c(3,1)),
             heights=c(1,3))
```

[image]

## Edit:

I couldn't find out what causes the space below the densities geoms. You can fiddle with the plot margins to avoid it, but I don't really like that.

```
p2 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=x,colour=factor(group),fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.00,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme0(plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,-0.48,2.2),"lines")) 

p3 <- ggplot(DF,aes(x=y,colour=factor(group),fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_density(alpha=0.5) + 
  coord_flip()  + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = NULL,breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL,breaks=NULL,expand=c(0.00,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme0(plot.margin = unit(c(0,1,1.2,-0.48),"lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: very nice! how can you make the density plots closer to the axis though, so that they are touching the bounding box of the plots like in original figure?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether there is a package that does that directly, but I'm sure this *can* be done in R. Transparency is easy: you add another two digits to the RGB specification of a color for a given transparency:

```
#FF0000 # red
#FF0000FF # full opacity
#FF000000 # full transparency
```

Combining different plots is also easy using the `layout` function. As for the vertical density plot, it is just the same as the horizontal plot with x and y switched. The example given [here](http://onertipaday.blogspot.de/2007/05/rotating-distribution-plot-by-90.html) can easily be expanded to include colors, smaller margins etc. I can try to come up with a more elaborate example if this description is not sufficient.