# Add density function in x and y direction

Tags: r

Once I found a post on this wbsite where someone plots his data with ggplot2. The special in the post was that he adds to the main plot a area with density functions in y-directions on the rigth, and a area for density functions in x-direction above the main plot. But I couldnt find this post again. I tried search pattern like "direction density [ggplot2]" and some more but couldn't find it.

Comment: The term you need is "marginals": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2/8545618#8545618

Comment: Many thx, I search more than a half hour with wrong key words.