# matplotlib: imshow a 2d array with plots of its marginal densities

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

How can one plot a 2d density with its marginal densities,
along the lines of
[scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2)
or
[2D plot with histograms / marginals](http://blog.mckuhn.de/2013/04/2d-plot-with-histograms-for-each.html),
in matplotlib ?
In outline,

```
    # I have --
A = a 2d numpy array >= 0
xdens ~ A.mean(axis=0)
ydens ~ A.mean(axis=1)

    # I want --
pl.imshow( A )
pl.plot( xdens ) narrow, below A
pl.plot( ydens ) narrow, left of A, with the x y axes flipped
```

---

Added in 2017: see the lovely example of [seaborn.jointplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/regression_marginals.html),
also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920885/how-to-overlay-a-seaborn-jointplot-with-a-marginal-distribution-histogram-fr) on SO. (The question was in 2013, before seaborn.)

Comment: I've looked everywhere and reached out to the maintainer of Python-ggplot but can't seem to do a plot around numpy arrays or matrices. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/141#issuecomment-31201433

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `sharex` and `sharey` with subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

t = np.linspace(0, 31.3, 100)
f = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1000)
a = np.exp(-np.abs(f-200)/200)[:, None] * np.random.rand(t.size)
flim = (f.min(), f.max())
tlim = (t.min(), t.max())

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[1,3], height_ratios=[3,1])
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0,1])
axl = plt.subplot(gs[0,0], sharey=ax)
axb = plt.subplot(gs[1,1], sharex=ax)

ax.imshow(a, origin='lower', extent=tlim+flim, aspect='auto')
plt.xlim(tlim)

axl.plot(a.mean(1), f)
axb.plot(t, a.mean(0))
```

Which gives you:

[image: subplots]