# How to overlay a Seaborn jointplot with a "marginal" (distribution histogram) from a different dataset

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, jointplot

I have plotted a Seaborn `JointPlot` from a set of "observed counts vs concentration" which are stored in a pandas `DataFrame`. I would like to overlay (on the same set of axes) a marginal (ie: univariate distribution) of the "expected counts" for each concentration on top of the existing marginal, so that the difference can be easily compared.

This graph is very similar to what I want, although it will have different axes and only two datasets:
[image]

Here is an example of how my data is laid out and related:

**df_observed**

```
x axis--> log2(concentration): 1,1,1,2,3,3,3 (zero-counts have been omitted)

y axis--> log2(count): 4.5, 5.7, 5.0, 9.3, 16.0, 16.5, 15.4 (zero-counts have been omitted)
```

**df_expected**

```
x axis--> log2(concentration): 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
```

an overlaying of the distribution of `df_expected` on top of that of `df_observed` would therefore indicate where there were counts missing at each concentration.

**What I currently have**

[image: Jointplot with the observed counts at each concentration]
[image: Separate jointplot of the expected counts at each concentration. I want the marginal from this plot to be overlaid on top of the marginal from the above jointplot]

PS: I am new to Stack Overflow so any suggestions about how to better ask questions will be met with gratitude. Also, I have searched extensively for an answer to my question but to no avail. In addition, a Plotly solution would be equally helpful. Thank you

Comment: Can you put a picture of what you already have? Just to give me a better idea for your case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added pictures of the two separate plots I wish to combine into one. Sorry for the poor explanation, I realise it is not as clear as one would like.

Comment: Do you have sample data? How is your data structured? A sample dataframe might be good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever I try to modify a JointPlot more than for what it was intended for, I turn to a JointGrid instead. It allows you to change the parameters of the plots in the marginals.

Below is an example of a working JointGrid where I add another histogram for each marginal. These histograms represent the expected value that you wanted to add. Keep in mind that I generated random data so it probably doesn't look like yours.

[image]

Take a look at the code, where I altered the range of each second histogram to match the range from the observed data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'])

plt.ion()
plt.show()
plt.pause(0.001)

p = sns.JointGrid(
    x = df['x'],
    y = df['y']
    )

p = p.plot_joint(
    plt.scatter
    )

p.ax_marg_x.hist(
    df['x'],
    alpha = 0.5
    )

p.ax_marg_y.hist(
    df['y'],
    orientation = 'horizontal',
    alpha = 0.5
    )

p.ax_marg_x.hist(
    df['z'],
    alpha = 0.5,
    range = (np.min(df['x']), np.max(df['x']))
    )

p.ax_marg_y.hist(
    df['w'],
    orientation = 'horizontal',
    alpha = 0.5,
    range = (np.min(df['y']), np.max(df['y'])),
    )
```

The part where I call `plt.ion plt.show plt.pause` is what I use to display the figure. Otherwise, no figure appears on my computer. You might not need this part.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you blue_chip! That was exactly what I was looking for... I am extremely grateful for the help, especially considering my poor explanation. Also, thanks to @mwaskom for the input.

Comment: For those having too many points, you can change the size `s` of the circles with `p = p.plot_joint(lambda x, y: plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, s=1.5))`

Answer (score 15):

Wrote a function to plot it, very loosly based on @blue_chip's idea.
You might still need to tweak it a bit for your specific needs.

Here is an example usage:

[image]

Example data:

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd
n=1000
m1=-3
m2=3

df1 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(n)+m1).reshape(-1,2), columns=['x','y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(n)+m2).reshape(-1,2), columns=['x','y'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values+df2.values, columns=['x','y'])
df1['kind'] = 'dist1'
df2['kind'] = 'dist2'
df3['kind'] = 'dist1+dist2'
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

Function definition:

```
def multivariateGrid(col_x, col_y, col_k, df, k_is_color=False, scatter_alpha=.5):
    def colored_scatter(x, y, c=None):
        def scatter(*args, **kwargs):
            args = (x, y)
            if c is not None:
                kwargs['c'] = c
            kwargs['alpha'] = scatter_alpha
            plt.scatter(*args, **kwargs)

        return scatter

    g = sns.JointGrid(
        x=col_x,
        y=col_y,
        data=df
    )
    color = None
    legends=[]
    for name, df_group in df.groupby(col_k):
        legends.append(name)
        if k_is_color:
            color=name
        g.plot_joint(
            colored_scatter(df_group[col_x],df_group[col_y],color),
        )
        sns.distplot(
            df_group[col_x].values,
            ax=g.ax_marg_x,
            color=color,
        )
        sns.distplot(
            df_group[col_y].values,
            ax=g.ax_marg_y,
            color=color,            
            vertical=True
        )
    # Do also global Hist:
    sns.distplot(
        df[col_x].values,
        ax=g.ax_marg_x,
        color='grey'
    )
    sns.distplot(
        df[col_y].values.ravel(),
        ax=g.ax_marg_y,
        color='grey',
        vertical=True
    )
    plt.legend(legends)
```

Usage:

```
multivariateGrid('x', 'y', 'kind', df=df)
```

Comment: This is great. But why does replacing the inner `scatter` function with just `plt.scatter` or `sns.scatterplot` result in the colours all being the same?

Comment: Wait, figured it out, it's a closure over the *grouped* x and y, discarding the `*args` passed to the function that `plot_joint` calls inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot directly onto the `JointGrid.ax_marg_x` and `JointGrid.ax_marg_y` attributes, which are the underlying matplotlib axes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see how that might be the solution I am looking for. I am having trouble implementing that, however. Could you please explain how to go about that? I have tried the following:                              `g = sns.jointplot(x=result['log2(Concentration[attomoles/ul])'], y=result['log2(tpm)'], kind="reg", xlim=(-7,15),
marginal_kws=dict(bins=22, kde=True), stat_func=r2, color="g", size=8)

g.ax_marg_x=concentrations_expected['log2(Concentration[attomoles/ul])']

Answer (score 0):

It's now in [Seaborn 0.11](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) with the `hue` parameter:

```
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
```

[image]