# matplotlib: plotting histogram plot just above scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make beautiful scatter plots with histograms above and right of the scatter plot, as it is possible in seaborn with jointplot:

[image: seaborn jointplot]

I am looking for suggestions on how to achieve this. In fact I am having some troubles in installing pandas, and also I do not need the entire seaborn module

Comment: To be clear, your question is how to implement `sns.jointplot` in vanilla matplotlib?

Comment: more or less. my question is how to place another box above  a scatter plot, so I can draw an histogram  there

Comment: Check out [`matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-with-varying-cell-sizes), specifically the example at the bottom.  Without gridspec, you can follow this [clear example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html)

Comment: Further, here's a similar example on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525983/matplotlib-imshow-a-2d-array-with-plots-of-its-marginal-densities

Comment: Matplotlib now has an own example on 'Show the marginal distributions of a scatter plot as histograms at the sides of the plot.': https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/scatter_hist_locatable_axes.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it, using `gridspec.GridSpec`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(50)
y = np.random.rand(50)

fig = plt.figure()

gs = GridSpec(4,4)

ax_joint = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4,0:3])
ax_marg_x = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0:3])
ax_marg_y = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4,3])

ax_joint.scatter(x,y)
ax_marg_x.hist(x)
ax_marg_y.hist(y,orientation="horizontal")

# Turn off tick labels on marginals
plt.setp(ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)

# Set labels on joint
ax_joint.set_xlabel('Joint x label')
ax_joint.set_ylabel('Joint y label')

# Set labels on marginals
ax_marg_y.set_xlabel('Marginal x label')
ax_marg_x.set_ylabel('Marginal y label')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: nice, but how do I remove ticks only from the histograms (without suppressing axes), and  how do I add labels selectively?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209467/matplotlib-share-x-axis-but-dont-show-x-axis-tick-labels-for-both-just-one

Comment: now my labels  appear on the plot [0,0] instead than [1,0]. I want ylabel on plot [0,0], xlabel on plot[1,1], and both labels on plot [1,0]

Answer (score 25):

I encountered the same problem today. Additionally I wanted a CDF for the marginals.

[image]

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

x = np.random.beta(2,5,size=int(1e4))
y = np.random.randn(int(1e4))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
ax_main = plt.subplot(gs[1:3, :2])
ax_xDist = plt.subplot(gs[0, :2],sharex=ax_main)
ax_yDist = plt.subplot(gs[1:3, 2],sharey=ax_main)
    
ax_main.scatter(x,y,marker='.')
ax_main.set(xlabel="x data", ylabel="y data")

ax_xDist.hist(x,bins=100,align='mid')
ax_xDist.set(ylabel='count')
ax_xCumDist = ax_xDist.twinx()
ax_xCumDist.hist(x,bins=100,cumulative=True,histtype='step',density=True,color='r',align='mid')
ax_xCumDist.tick_params('y', colors='r')
ax_xCumDist.set_ylabel('cumulative',color='r')

ax_yDist.hist(y,bins=100,orientation='horizontal',align='mid')
ax_yDist.set(xlabel='count')
ax_yCumDist = ax_yDist.twiny()
ax_yCumDist.hist(y,bins=100,cumulative=True,histtype='step',density=True,color='r',align='mid',orientation='horizontal')
ax_yCumDist.tick_params('x', colors='r')
ax_yCumDist.set_xlabel('cumulative',color='r')

plt.show()
```

Hope it helps the next person searching for scatter-plot with marginal distribution.

Comment: Your pic is beautiful, +1, but the code returns an error: `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no property 'normed'`. Please correct your solution or tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Figured it out: replace `normed=True` with `density=True`.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to flip the right histogram  by adding these 3 lines of code to the [current best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469428/3671939) before `plt.show()` :

```
ax_yDist.invert_xaxis()
ax_yDist.yaxis.tick_right()
ax_yCumDist.invert_xaxis()
```

[image: after flipping the right histogram]

The advantage is that any person who is visualizing it can compare easily the two histograms just by moving and rotating clockwise the right histogram on their mind.

On contrast, in the plot of the question and in all other answers, if you want to compare the two histograms, your first reaction is to rotate the right histogram counterclockwise, which leads to wrong conclusions because the y axis gets inverted. Indeed, the right CDF of the [current best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469428/3671939) looks decreasing at first sight:

[image: before flipping the right histogram]