# How to align several subplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to have four plots with images. All channels, and one for Red, Green and Blue channel. For RGB I'd like to plot a color profile across columns and rows. I would like to have the profile plots aligned exactly to the corresponding image. I mean their width and length should match to width and length, of an image. Their heights should be equal.

For now I achieved this effect using `GridSpec`. I know I can manipualte by changing fig size proportions, but it is not the solution. I need exact fit.

[image]

Here is my code.

```py
    def show_signal_across_image(self):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 9), dpi=109)
        gs = GridSpec(4, 4,
                      height_ratios=[10, 2, 10, 2],
                      width_ratios=[10, 2, 10, 2],
                      left=0.05,
                      right=1 - 0.03,
                      top=0.95,
                      bottom=0.06,
                      hspace=0.3,
                      wspace=0.4)
        ax_all = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
        ax_red_img = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
        ax_green_img = fig.add_subplot(gs[8])
        ax_blue_img = fig.add_subplot(gs[10])

        ax_red_signal_horizontal = fig.add_subplot(gs[6], sharex=ax_red_img)
        ax_red_signal_vertical = fig.add_subplot(gs[3], sharey=ax_red_img)

        ax_green_signal_horizontal = fig.add_subplot(gs[12], sharex=ax_green_img)
        ax_green_signal_vertical = fig.add_subplot(gs[9], sharey=ax_green_img)

        ax_blue_signal_horizontal = fig.add_subplot(gs[14], sharex=ax_blue_img)
        ax_blue_signal_vertical = fig.add_subplot(gs[11], sharey=ax_blue_img)

        signals = self.get_signal_values()
        red_horizontal, red_vertical, green_horizontal, green_vertical, blue_horizontal, blue_vertical = signals
        horizontal_signals = [red_horizontal, green_horizontal, blue_horizontal]
        vertical_signals = [red_vertical, green_vertical, blue_vertical]
        max_value_horizontal = max([item for sublist in horizontal_signals for item in sublist])
        max_value_vertical = max([item for sublist in vertical_signals for item in sublist])

        ax_red_signal_horizontal.plot(red_horizontal)
        ax_green_signal_horizontal.plot(green_horizontal)
        ax_blue_signal_horizontal.plot(blue_horizontal)

        ax_red_signal_vertical.plot(red_vertical, np.arange(len(red_vertical)))
        ax_green_signal_vertical.plot(green_vertical, np.arange(len(green_vertical)))
        ax_blue_signal_vertical.plot(blue_vertical, np.arange(len(blue_vertical)))

        ax_red_signal_vertical.invert_xaxis()
        ax_green_signal_vertical.invert_xaxis()
        ax_blue_signal_vertical.invert_xaxis()

        for ax in [ax_red_signal_horizontal, ax_green_signal_horizontal, ax_blue_signal_horizontal]:
            ax.set_ylim(0, max_value_horizontal * 1.1)
        for ax in [ax_red_signal_vertical, ax_green_signal_vertical, ax_blue_signal_vertical]:
            ax.set_xlim(max_value_vertical * 1.1, 0)

        imshow_args = dict(vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='gray')
        plt.subplot(ax_all)
        plt.title('All channels')
        plt.imshow(self.img, **imshow_args)
        plt.subplot(ax_red_img)
        plt.title('Red')
        plt.imshow(self.red, **imshow_args)
        plt.subplot(ax_green_img)
        plt.title('Green')
        plt.imshow(self.green, **imshow_args)
        plt.subplot(ax_blue_img)
        plt.title('Blue')
        plt.imshow(self.blue, **imshow_args)

        plt.show()
```

I'm using matplotlib 3.1.1 and python 3.7.1.

Comment: in fact `GridSpec` is exactly what you need. You may just not merge them correctly. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008112/matplotlib-plotting-histogram-plot-just-above-scatter-plot)

Comment: You probably need to try: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/toolkits/axes_grid.html