# ggplot2: add conditional density curves describing both dimensions of scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have scatterplots of 2D data from two categories. I want to add density lines for each dimension -- not outside the plot (cf. [Scatterplot with marginal histograms in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2)) but right on the plotting surface. I can get this for the x-axis dimension, like this:

```
set.seed(123)
dim1 <- c(rnorm(100, mean=1), rnorm(100, mean=4))
dim2 <- rnorm(200, mean=1)
cat <- factor(c(rep("a", 100), rep("b", 100)))
mydf <- data.frame(cbind(dim2, dim1, cat))
ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, colour=as.factor(cat))) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_density(aes(x=dim1, y=(-2+(..scaled..))), 
  position="identity", geom="line")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

But I want an analogous pair of density curves running vertically, showing the distribution of points in the y-dimension.  I tried

```
stat_density(aes(y=dim2, x=0+(..scaled..))), position="identity", geom="line)
```

but receive the error "stat_density requires the following missing aesthetics: x".

Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: I added your plot (pending review).  This looks like a tough one.  I wonder if `coord_flip` is useful here

Comment: This is interesting, although it's not what you're looking for:  `ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, colour=as.factor(cat))) + stat_density2d()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the densities of the dim2 variables.  Then, flip the axes and store them in a new data.frame.  After that it is simply plotting them on top of the other graph.

```
p <- ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, colour=as.factor(cat))) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_density(aes(x=dim1, y=(-2+(..scaled..))), 
               position="identity", geom="line")

stuff <- ggplot_build(p)
xrange <- stuff[[2]]$ranges[[1]]$x.range  # extract the x range, to make the new densities align with y-axis

## Get densities of dim2
ds <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(mydf$cat), function(lev) {
    dens <- with(mydf, density(dim2[cat==lev]))
    data.frame(x=dens$y+xrange[1], y=dens$x, cat=lev)
}))

p + geom_path(data=ds, aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(cat)))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution.  Kicking myself for not using `density`

Comment: thanks, it looks like ggplot might scale the y-values of the density a bit?  Your curves after the coord_flip look a little bit "taller".

Comment: If the original dataset had a factor (4-way, let's say) that I was using to facet_grid, any thoughts on how to modify the density extraction do.call to pull that data out?

Comment: @DSwingley You might need a nested `lapply` to get densities, one for each facet and one for each category in the facets.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks.  I'm struggling to do the lapply part, will post if I succeed.  So far errors with:  mydf$mytype <- factor(rep(c("I", "J", "K", "L"),50))    and then     ds3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(mydf$mytype), (lapply(unique(mydf$cat), function(lev) {
  dens <- with(mydf, density(dim2[cat==lev]))
  data.frame(x=dens$y+xrange[1], y=dens$x, cat=lev)
}))))

Comment: @DSwingley post a new question if you want, the code will get too long for the comments I think.

Answer (score 2):

So far I can produce:

```
distrib_horiz <- stat_density(aes(x=dim1, y=(-2+(..scaled..))), 
                              position="identity", geom="line")

ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, colour=as.factor(cat))) + 
  geom_point() + distrib_horiz
```

[image]

And:

```
distrib_vert <- stat_density(data=mydf, aes(x=dim2, y=(-2+(..scaled..))), 
                             position="identity", geom="line") 

ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=dim2, y=dim1, colour=as.factor(cat))) + 
  geom_point() + distrib_vert + coord_flip()
```

[image]

But combining them is proving tricky.

Comment: retaining stat_density in a data structure seems like a nice start (if one could draw a line from it, ggplot wouldn't have to know where the x,y's came from).  But I'm not sure how to access the density data.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have only a partial solution since I didn't manage to obtain a vertical `stat_density` line for each individual category, only for the total set. Maybe this can nevertheless help as a starting point for finding a better solution. My suggestion is to try with the `ggMarginal()` function from the `ggExtra` package.

```
p <- ggplot(data=mydf, aes(x=dim1, y=dim2, colour=as.factor(cat))) + 
  geom_point() + stat_density(aes(x=dim1, y=(-2+(..scaled..))), 
           position="identity", geom="line")
library(ggExtra)
ggMarginal(p,type = "density", margins = "y", size = 4)
```

This is what I obtain:
[image]

I know it's not perfect, but maybe it's a step in a helpful direction. At least I hope so. Looking forward to seeing other answers.