# Is it possible to create a kernel density plot like one below in R? (I am not looking for scatter plots!)

Tags: r, ggplot2, seaborn, kernel-density

Is it possible to have distribution of each variable plotted separately, like
what seaborn does, in ggplot?
It seems all solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2) are related to scatter plots, except the first one which could be kind of ugly.

[image]

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.lreding.com/nonstandard_deviations/2017/08/19/cowmarg/

Comment: The plot image is OK but please don't post **code** as an image. Can you post it as code?