# Scatter plot with normal marginals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, normal-distribution

How can you add normal marginal distributions to a plot in R?

Here is an example code and I would like to have normal marginals added to the sides (top and right side):

```
x<- rweibull(100, 2.6, 3)
y<- rweibull(100, 1.8, 3)
xy.df<- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
p1<- ggplot(xy.df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.25) +
  geom_density2d() +
  theme_classic() +
    border()
ggMarginal(p1, type="density")
```

Comment: What is a "normal marginal"? Do you mean a histogram superimposed with a density curve? If so, try `type = "densigram"`.

Comment: @ekoam I meant the theoretical normal distribution.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a theoretical normal density, you can do that with the **cowplot** package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

x <- 1:30
y <- x + rnorm(30, 0, 1)
dat <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

gg <- ggplot(dat) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))

y_density <- axis_canvas(gg, axis = "y", coord_flip = TRUE) +
  geom_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 15, sd = 5)) +
  coord_flip()

# create the combined plot
combined_plot <- insert_yaxis_grob(gg, y_density, position = "right")

# show the result
ggdraw(combined_plot)
```

[image]

Comment: The answer is close to what I need, and that's because I wasn't clear enough. I apologize for that! I would like to add the theoretical normal distribution along with the empirical distribution. So each side, right and top, should have two density plots: a theoretical normal and an empirical distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late, but you can accomplish what you want from the `ggside` package. You will need to use the `dev` version from the [github](https://github.com/jtlandis/ggside/tree/dev) to use the the full functionality though.

Currently, the CRAN version of `ggside` does not have `(x|y)side` variants to `stat_function()`, but the current dev branch has a version working.

Here we plot the normal density estimates filled in with blue, and then the theoretical distribution is colored red.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggside)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'ggside':
#>   method from   
#>   +.gg   ggplot2
x<- rweibull(100, 2.6, 3)
y<- rweibull(100, 1.8, 3)
xy.df<- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
p <- ggplot(xy.df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.25) +
  geom_density2d() +
  geom_xsidedensity(fill = "blue", alpha = .3) +
  geom_ysidedensity(fill = "blue", alpha = .3) +
  stat_xsidefunction(fun = dweibull, args = list(shape = 1.8, scale = 3), colour = "red") +
  stat_ysidefunction(fun = dweibull, args = list(shape = 2.6, scale = 3), colour = "red") +
  theme_classic() 
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>